# Exponential generating function to distribute $20$ people in $6$ rooms

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, generating-functions

Find an Exponential generating function to distribute $20$ people in $6$ rooms such that each rooms contains either $2,3$ or $4$ people.

I could only create normal generating function $$(x^2+x^3+x^4)^6$$ wherein we find coefficient of $x^{20}$. But how to form exponential generating function?

I saw the related question here [Find the exponential generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015865/find-the-exponential-generating-function)

But i could not understand.

Comment: If you were distributing identical objects to $6$ different rooms then $(x^2+x^3+x^4)^6$ would work but here it is people and it matters which persons go to which room but the order does not matter for person within a room. So if rooms $1$ to $6$ have $2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4$ people in that order, the number of arrangements is $ \dfrac{20!}{2! ~ 4! ~ 3! ~ 4! ~ 3! ~ 4!}$. That is why you set up the generating function as $ \displaystyle  \left( \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^6 ~$ and you find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ and multiply by $20!$

Comment: It's called exponential generating function as the terms are part of the Maclaurin series for $e^x$

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation

Comment: @MathLover  You should transform your comments into an answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sure, I did write it as an answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were distributing identical objects to $6$ different rooms with each room having $2, 3$ or $4$ objects then the generating function would be $(x^2+x^3+x^4)^6$ and we would look for coefficient of $x^{20}$ as there are $20$ objects. But when it comes to distinct objects, this generating function does not work. Let's take this question as example.

We are assigning people to different rooms and it matters which persons go to which room but the order does not matter for persons within a room. So if rooms $1 - 6~$ have $~2, 4, 3, 4, 3 \text { and } 4$ people respectively, the number of arrangements is

$ \displaystyle {20 \choose 2} {18 \choose 4}{14 \choose 3}{11 \choose 4}{7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 4}~,$ which is equal to

$~ \dfrac{20!}{2! ~ 4! ~3!~ 4!~ 3!~ 4! }$.

That is why we set up the generating function as $ \displaystyle \left(\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac {x^3}{3!} + \frac {x^4}{4!} \right)^6$  and once we find the coefficient of $x^{20}$, we multiply by $20!~$.

It's called exponential generating function as the terms are part of the Maclaurin series for $e^x$.